# Custom Framework Import iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-frameworks

So I have a custom framework I created for my iOS Apps that works great, but the import works differently than Apple's included frameworks and I was wondering why/how to fix it.

Example

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h> //Apple
#import "MyFramework.framework/Headers/MyFramework.h" //Me
```

Desired:

```
#import "MyFramework/MyFramework.h"
```

Comment: Did you try <MyFramework/MyFramework.h> ?

Answer (score 0):

From [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/IncludingFrameworks.html):

> If your project links to frameworks that are not included in any of
>   the standard locations, you must explicitly specify the location of
>   that framework before Xcode can locate its header files. To specify
>   the location of such a framework, add the directory containing the
>   framework to the “Framework Search Paths” option of your Xcode
>   project. Xcode passes this list of directories to the compiler and
>   linker, which both use the list to search for the framework resources.

You can set Framework Search Paths in your Target / Build Settings:

[image: Target / Build Settings / Framework Search Paths]

After that you should be able to import your framework, using standard `<MyFramework/MyFramework.h>` notation.